# Any other way of clearing old tasks and creating new tasks without using mainIntent?

Tags: android

so im trying to clear all tasks when i press the back button on the phone. but im getting an error of `Cannot resolve symbol 'mainIntent'` from this code:

```
 Intent login_intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                            mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(login_intent);
                            finish();
```

is there anywhere i went wrong or is there another way i can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trychange name 'mainIntent' to 'login_intent'

```
Intent login_intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                            login_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(login_intent);
                            finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this you pass wrong intent name.

```
 Intent login_intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                        login_intent .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(login_intent);
                        finish();
```